# Notification placement on website with notify.js

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to show global notifications using bootstrap and notify.js(http://notifyjs.com/) /jQuery. I have no problems getting the notifications to work using the following code:

```
$.notify('successfully logged in','succes');
```

However I want the notification to appear in the top right corner below the bootstrap navbar or in other words, I want the top notification to appear 50px below the page top.

Using `"margin-top":"50px"` in the base class seems to work, but the second notification also appears 50px lower.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've played a bit with the example on http://notifyjs.com. All global notifications are added to a container `<div>` with class `.notifyjs-corner`. Looking through the source code it seems that there is not option to override the default css styling on this class. The container gets its positioning set by adding inline styling to the html element. One way to override this would be for example:

```
.notifyjs-corner {
    top: 70px !important;
}
```

Another, I think preferable, solution would be to not use global notifications, but to create your own positioning element. For example create an element like `<div class="notifications">`, position it using your own css and add notifications to it using `$('.notifications').notify('successfully logged in', 'success');`